# Why is Router IP Address Repeated in Trace Command?

Tags: cisco, router

I have a network that is a branch of our central office.
The central office is located in another city and I connect to the central office with a Cisco router using a leased line E1 cable(using Telco).

When the telco line is down and I ping the branch office it gives me a

```
Reply from 192.168.1.254: TTL expired in transit.
```

message, and if I turn off the router it gives me a

```
Request timed out.
```

message. The problem is that when the telco line is down and I trace the central office it gives me this:

```
192.168.1.254  ==> is my router ip address
192.168.20.118 ==> is my central office


C:\Users\johnny>tracert -d 192.168.20.118

Tracing route to 192.168.0.112 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.190
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.254
  3     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.254
  4     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.254
  5     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
  6     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
  7     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
  8     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
  9     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 10     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 11     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 12     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 13     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 14     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 15     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 16     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 17     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 18     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 19     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 20     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.254
 30     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.254
Trace complete.
```

what seems to be the problem that it returns my router address in trace continuously?

Comment: I suppose you are looking at a routing loop. That will need solving, yes.

Comment: @FelixFrank In case of a routing loop, you would see it looping through the IP addresses of the routers in the loop. But the trace has only one IP repeating. A routing loop combined with something NATing the ICMP errors could explain it. Otherwise something weird would have to be going on in the routing table causing the router to forward packets to itself without noticing. Either way the routing table from `192.168.1.254` should contain some clues.

Comment: @FelixFrank: In addition to the routing table, capture captures with a tool like tcp might provide insight. In particular observe the IP header.

Comment: The IP addresses in your example tracert don't jive.  Where did 192.168.0.112 come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a routing loop, I too faced this kind of issues. But not in the Router instead on the server.

We tried rebooting the server. It did not fixed the trouble, Later Server team upgraded the firmware then it started working fine.